# Dev express Grid View – Column Visible Index property giving un expected output

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have dev express grid view, and trying to set column visibility run time, Some columns are not appearing in correct order i.e. `RebateAmount` i want to set to appear at 4th position but its appearing always on second position, any idea what's wrong in below code? i want all columns should be appear at position which i have set in visibility index.

```
if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("TaxName"))
{
    currentColum.Caption = @"abc";
}
else if (intGridType == 1 || intGridType == 0)//Both
{
    if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCurrentCollectionTotal"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 15;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCurrentCollectionVyajTotal"))
    {
        currentColum.Caption = @"Äyij";
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 16;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCurrentCollectionNoticeFeeTotal"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 17;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("RebateAmount"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 18;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCurrentCollectionTotalTotal"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 19;
    }
    else
        currentColum.Visible = false;
}
else if (intGridType == 2)//Only Past
{
    if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCollection"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 6;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCollectionVyaj"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 7;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCollectionNoticeFee"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 8;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("PastCollectionTotal"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 9;
    }
    else
        currentColum.Visible = false;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(currentColum.VisibleIndex.ToString() + currentColum.Name);
}
else if (intGridType == 3) //Only Current
{
    if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("CurrentCollection"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 10;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("CurrentCollectionVyaj"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 11;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("CurrentCollectionNoticeFee"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 12;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("CurrentCollectionTotal"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 13;
    }
    else if (currentColum.FieldName.Equals("RebateAmount"))
    {
        currentColum.Visible = true;
        currentColum.VisibleIndex = 14;
    }
    else
        currentColum.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hide all columns and active ( Visible = true) one at a time in order you want